# Hide or show charts in SSRS based on parameter

Tags: charts, visibility, reporting-services

I understand that if I enter the following

```
=IIf(Parameters!HOURINPUT.Value = "1", true, false)
```

into a charts Visibility field, I can make it appear only when the users chooses 1 from the available options.

What need is to do is have 24 charts, and show only one at a time, based on the parameter value. And if the user chooses "All" as the option, then show them all.

My HOURINPUT parameter gives the user the following options: 1, 2, 3, 4, ... 22, 23, All

Is it possible to decide which chart to show in an expression and to show them all if the user chooses All? Or what would be the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add all 24 charts to the report and then set the visibility for each as you describe above. You could also use a parameter that allows for [multiple values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337292%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) if you think users might want some particular combination of charts: this would require some slight changes to your visibility expression.

Or if you want to get fancy, you could create a dataset that returns the selected parameters:

```
--Assuming Multiple selection allowed.
Select 1 As HourNum WHERE 1 in ( @HOURINPUT ) OR 'All' in (@HOURINPUT)
UNION ALL
Select 2 As HourNum WHERE 2 in ( @HOURINPUT ) OR 'All' in (@HOURINPUT)
UNION ALL
  ...
```

Then create a table (or Tablix) using this dataset: add one chart, but put an =iif expression into the data series for the chart that takes the appropriate data for that hour. This might be easier if all 24 charts are very close in data and layout.